# How to remove first number on a 5th line in unix?

Tags: unix, sed

Is there any other way than using sed like this :

```
sed '5 s/[0-9][0-9]*//' filename
```

Comment: what is the problem with this solution?

Comment: You can use perl too ;) But this solution is just fine. Maybe you can use `sed -i` for in-place replacement.

Comment: Won't work for number with decimals

Comment: @perreal no problem as such. Just curious to know if that is the only way.

Comment: @NirajW, then it is not the only way. You can do this with perl, python, awk, bash, C, C++, Java, ... I don't know. IMO is a terrible question

Answer (score 0):

You can use this `sed`:

```
sed '5 s/[0-9]\+\(\.[0-9]\+\)\?//' file
```

This will removed both numbers and number with decimals also.

Comment: Edit for just the 5th line. This looks fine considering decimals as well.

Comment: @NirajW, Updated answer.

Comment: Thanks for answering.Helped a lot!!

Comment: @NirajW, If this answer helped to solve your problem, consider accepting it by clicking tick mark on right side of answer. More: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work/5235#5235